# Async file write and check the file size

Tags: node.js, csv, asynchronous

Desired Output : I want to write to csv file and check if it exceeds to some size then create another csv file and write to it & repeat process.

So far, I am able to write to csv file using npm module called 'csv-write-stream'.

```
function writeToFile(data) {
  writer = csvWriter({sendHeaders: true});
  writer.pipe(ws);
  writer.write(data);
  writer.end();
}

function init() { 
  ws = fs.createWriteStream(fileName, {flags: 'a'});
  fs.watchFile(fileName, function(curr, prev) {
    if (curr.size > maxFileSizeInBytes) {
      console.log('size exceeds, switch to another file for writing.');
    }
  });
}

init();
writToFile({data:....});
writToFile({data:....});
writToFile({data:....});
```

The above code works Ok, the problem is first it writes to file and then execution comes to watchFile's callback, and with this approach how do I hold data if size exceeds and write it to another file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find any module which does writing and checking the file size async but found one github repo which helped a lot in resolving this problem.

[Streamroller](https://github.com/nomiddlename/streamroller)